# Tools for describing JSON schemas

Tags: json, specifications, diagrams

I'm writing a spec and need to describe some JSON objects. Big JSONs tend to get too confusing with text and tabs alone. Is there any online (preferably) tool to create diagrams like the ones on http://www.json.org/ or http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html. They use them to describe syntax, but, is there anything like it to describe JSON objects ? They are great to represent objects that are required, optional, arrays, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These types of syntax diagrams are known as "railroad diagrams".

There is an online tool at https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui that you can use to generate tour own diagrams.  You must specify your grammar in EBNF notation.